# Elasticsearch: script fields in nested query

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there a way to use a "script_fields" in a nested query adding fields to the returned inner_hits? Example:

```
{
   "nested": {
      "inner_hits": {},
      "path": "companies",
      "score_mode": "sum",
      "query": {},
      "script_fields": {
         "overlap" : {
            "script": {
               "source": "................................",
               "params": {
                   "from": "2012-01-01",
                    "to": "2015-06-30"
                }
            }
         }                
      }         
}
```

I execute n nested queries passing to each one a set of specific params. The idea is having the source script to assign a value to the overlap field for each one of the inner hits based on the provided params.

#### Update after Val suggestion on adding script_fields into the inner hits

Looks like executing more nested queries on the same nested path defining different inner_hits makes ES to strip inner_hits matches. Example:

```
{
       "nested": {
          "inner_hits": {
            "script_fields": {
               "overlap" : {
                  "script": {
                     "source": "................................",
                        "params": {
                           "from": "2012-01-01",
                           "to": "2015-06-30"
                         }
                      }
                   }                
                 } 
          },
          "path": "companies",
          "score_mode": "sum",
          "query": {},

    },
    {
       "nested": {
          "inner_hits": {
            "script_fields": {
               "overlap" : {
                  "script": {
                     "source": "................................",
                        "params": {
                           "from": "2012-01-01",
                           "to": "2015-06-30"
                         }
                      }
                   }                
                 } 
          },
          "path": "companies",
          "score_mode": "sum",
          "query": {},

    }
```

If a run more nested query like these I get the correct matches but not all the expected inner_hits are returned. I can obtain all the hits only giving a random name to the different inner_hits like:

```
"inner_hits": {
   "name": [random name]
   "script_fields": {
      "overlap" : {
         ......
      }
    }
 }
```

Then I get the correct hits results but with some downside. I must check for duplicated results as hits are added to different result sets and are not uniq anymore. I have to parse the results using a regex for rebuilding a unified list.

Does this sounds like a bug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes that's doable. you simply need to move the `script_fields` section inside `inner_hits`, like this:

```
{
   "nested": {
      "path": "companies",
      "score_mode": "sum",
      "query": {}.
      "inner_hits": {
         "script_fields": {
           "overlap" : {
             "script": {
               "source": "................................",
               "params": {
                   "from": "2012-01-01",
                    "to": "2015-06-30"
               }
             }
           }                
         }     
      }
   }              
}
```

Comment: Yep this is working. Adding the script_fields into the inner_hits works ... even if is not documented. While I thought this was the answer to my issue my use case opens a new challenge as I need to execute n nested query and I MUST defined a n inner_hits {script_fields: ...} for each one of them since the params are I need to calculate the scripted fields are different by query. I have updated the example in the the question

Comment: Why not sending your queries in a [multi-search](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html)?

Comment: Because I would have more "parent" matches while I want to match "parents" executing n query on the nested array and having back the hits with some extra calculated field. Make sense?

Comment: Actually, we should have closed this question since the initial need is solved and you should have created a new question with the new problem.

Comment: OK I will close and create a new question.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!!!! I hate google that it doesn't promotes such stack pages to the top

Comment: @Val sorry, but could you help? how to access nested field in script, not just a constant? and I see that inner hits lost original fields, how can I keep original fields as well? Thank you!

Comment: @simplygood feel free to create a new question with your exact use case

Comment: @Val it is ready, thank you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67178903/elasticsearch-include-geo-distance-for-each-nested-object-and-sort-by-0-elemen