# Elasticsearch include geo_distance for each nested object and sort by [0] element.distance

Tags: elasticsearch, nested, distance

I have the following mappings:

```
properties: {
                locations: {
                    type: 'nested',
                    properties: {
                        location: {
                            type: 'geo_point'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

And use this query for filtering documents

```
body: {
  query: {
    bool: {
      must: [{
        nested: {
          path: 'locations',
          query: {
            bool: {
              filter: {
                geo_distance: {
                  distance: '300km',
                  'locations.location': {
                    lat: 32.77918970616056,
                    lon: -96.79523206899606
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          inner_hits: {} //inner_hits here is for returning matched array elements
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

This is an example of document I insert into index:

```
{
  id: 5,
  name: 'My favorite name',
  locations: [{
      location: {
        lat: 35.57798637393296,
        lon: -97.33606463928675
      }
    },
    {
      location: {
        lat: 32.78743712185017,
        lon: -96.80344505382367
      }
    }
  ],
}
```

And I look for an ability to include calculated distance into inner_hits (or into just locations, this doesn't matter).
From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51849159/elasticsearch-script-fields-in-nested-query/51852776?noredirect=1#comment118744234_51852776) I found that for appending fields to the result I can specify the script in `inner_hits` property like

```
inner_hits: {
  script_fields: {
    distance: {
      script: "1" //inner_hits will have distance property = 1
    }
  }
}
```

But I do not understand how to access location property and call `.distanceInKm(32.77918970616056, -96.79523206899606)` . Moreover, this approach seems to delete all other properties from the inner_hits  and only 'distance' property is left. I need to save original properties as well. And later use calculated distance of the [0] element for sorting resulting set.

Comment: DON'T use the `script` tag. Every SO question is about scripts one way or another. It's no better than adding `code` as a tag. That tag is just noise, it was deleted in the past and will be deleted very soon again.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos it is just Elasticsearch terminology and I thought this might be useful. But I got your point. Thanks

Comment: @simply-good - did you ever make progress on that problem? 

On the "I do not understand how to access location properties" part: does 

`doc['locations.location.lat'].value` 

work for you, i.e., using the full path despite being inside the inner_hit?